# How to handle errors from multiple independent promises inside a single route handler in express?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, middleware

I have an Express route handler that needs to start multiple operations asynchronously. These operations are indepentend and do not interfere with each other.
I tried to do this with Promises, but I have problems when I have to handle errors from Promises.

Let me explain with an example.

```
router.post('/data', function (req, res, next) {
  // do something before anything else
  next();
}, function (req, res, next) {

promise1(req.params)
  .then((data) => {
    // do something with data
  }).catch((err) => {
  next(err);
  });

promise2(req.params)
  .then((data) => {
    // do something with data
  }).catch((err) => {
    next(err);
  });

}, function (err, req, res, next) {
  // error middleware
});
```

The problem is that if both the 2 promises incur into errors, they both end up calling next(err) in the middleware and there is a problem here.

The second call to next(err) ends up in nothing and the middleware does not handle anything.

I'm looking for suggestions on a couple of things:

1. Is calling multiple promises in sequence an ok design somehow?
2. If yes, how should I handle errors?
3. If no, what is a good design pattern in this case?

**tldr** I must run multiple independent functions in a single express route and I don't know how to handle possible errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all` like this:

```
Promise.all([promise1(req.params), promise2(req.params)])
  .then(results => {
    // both succeeded
    // do something with results[0] and results[1]
  }).catch(err => {
    // some error happend
    next(err);
  });
```

See the docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

See also [other answers about `Promise.all`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A613198+Promise.all) for more examples.

Comment: But this gives me a problem if both the promises incur in error. the first error is correctely forwarded to the middleware, but the second gives me an Unhandled Error on the reject(err) call inside the promise.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `Promise.all` as `rsp` already answered.
I'd also suggest handling the error response right in the catch block e.g.

```
.catch(error => {
  res.status(500).end("An error occured: " + error);
});
```

instead of pulling these errors through more middlewares via `next()`.

Comment: But what if I would like to centralize error handling in an error function so I can apply a sequence of actions to every kind of error? For instance, logging